# Rails shows all migrations as pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, heroku, rake

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is successfully running on Heroku.

I did some experimentation with RSpec and Cucumber, but at some point running the server locally failed with the message

> Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake
>   db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

I ran `rake db:migrate:status` and literally all 50 or so of my migrations are marked as "down", even ones created months ago:

[image: migrations down]

When I try to run the command it gives me, it gives me

```
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "artists" already exists
```

which is fair enough since it does, it's an old migration.  So the problem is that it's not detecting that these migrations were already run.

Here's what I've tried:

- A `git reset` to the last working state (my heroku instance)
- Restarting Postgres, the rails server and my Mac
- Running `rake db:reset`, as well as `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

None of which worked.  I'm desperate to get my app back into a state where I can continue development on it.

Comment: What is the output when you run `rake db:reset` ?

Comment: You have 88 pending migrations: <lists migrations> Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.

Comment: The fastest workaround I can think of is changing the database name in `config/database.yml`  and starting over with new database.